# Can any Bluemix application run on AWS? or Local server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I know this kind of question is basic concept of bluemix but, I just worder if I develop an application on public bluemix using certain runtime, such as Node.js or Liberty, can this application run on my own Local server or AWS?
Is it depends on bluemix-provided services that I bind to application?
or If I install cloudfoundry on my local server or AWS cloud host, can the application run without any problem or issue?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out [Lattice](https://lattice.cf). It will allow you to run your own local or AWS hosted minimal cloudfoundry runtime. This will allow you to run your applications. If the services you are talking to are publicly accessible ie. Have a publicly routable host and port, then you can expose them as environment variables in your CF app manifest and reach out to them from your own CF or you could look at user provided services. You will need to upload buildpacks to your lattice/cf installation that are not a part of the standard installation.

DISCLAIMER: Lattice is useful during development and NOT recommended for production use. You should setup the entire cloudfoundry for that.

Comment: Thank you very much.. So, you're saying that If I want to run the bluemix application on AWS or on-premises, cloudfoundry or Lattice should be installed. because I use cloudfoundry runtime if I develop an application on bluemix. is it right?

Comment: So, I mean, is there no way to run the bluemix application on other environment without installing cloudfoundry or Lattice?

Comment: That's right. If you want the benefits of a cloudfoundry runtime, you need a platform. As a developer, I usually write my own apps locally and once I am satisfied with the application I write a manifest and `cf push`

If the app is using the diego runtime it supports docker containers, you can run the application locally in docker containers and push it to your CF environment. I am not sure if bluemix supports this functionality. [Docker with CF on Diego](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/diego-design-notes/blob/master/docker-support.md)

Comment: Thank you very much! but two more thing.. 1. If I developed an application in   local not using cloudfoundry runtimes, can I push my application to bluemix? I mean, If I built an application without awareness of Bluemix or Cloudfoundry, is it possible to push this app on bluemix?    2. If I use docker image, can I push an application from bluemix to AWS without installing cloudfoundry on AWS?

Comment: That really depends on the type of application, but most Liberty and Node.js applications should run on Bluemix/CloudFoundry without much/any work.